# Android drawable with image and background

Tags: android

I want to load a blue/transparent image into an android drawable. I want the drawable to have a orange background.
Is this possible without editing my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Layer List drawable with the bottom layer solid orange and the top layer your image.